# how secure is php's die()? (with & without output buffering)

Tags: php

Does die() successfully terminate the php script at that point or only with output bufferring?

would it be secure to do a:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    die('you do not have permission to access this page.');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From PHP.net :

> Terminates execution of the script.
>   Shutdown functions  and object
>   destructors  will always be executed
>   even if exit()  is called.

Die is just an equivalent for exit().

In your case nothing would happen later since you probably haven't defined shutdown function to be something a guest isn't supposed to run :)

[register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

[destructors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is secure.

Frankly, `die()` is equal to regular script end. Calling `die()` is the same as if you just delete everything below this line.